# Scrolling Background Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a element called content and 3 buttons "portfolio","about","contact". I want the background to scroll to a certain part for each one I click. At the moment there is animation for each scroll like so

```
@-webkit-keyframes toPortfolioBg {
    from {background-position:inherit; }
    to {background-position: 0px ;}
}   
@-webkit-keyframes toAboutBg {
    from {background-position: inherit;}
    to {background-position: 1920px ;}  
}
@-webkit-keyframes toContactBg {
    from {background-position: inherit; }
    to {background-position: 3840px ;}  
}
```

and the js which runs each animation when I click on each button

```
$(".portfolio").click(function() {
    reset()
    $("#portfolio").show(); 
    $("#content").css({"-webkit-animation": "toPortfolioBg 5s forwards" });     
    $("#content").css({"animation": "toPortfolioBg 5s forwards" });     
})
$(".about").click(function() {
    reset()
    $("#about").show();
    $("#content").css({"-webkit-animation": "toAboutBg 5s forwards" });         
    $("#content").css({"animation": "toAboutBg 5s forwards" });
})
$(".contact").click(function() {
    reset()
    $("#contact").show();
    $("#content").css({"-webkit-animation": "toContactBg 5s forwards" }); 
    $("#content").css({"animation": "toContactBg 5s forwards" }); 
})
```

however at the moment it is going straight back to the first image then scrolls whenever it does any animation. I want it to scroll to a certain position from the current position. Is it possible?

Note: Here is a link to the picture I am scrolling. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLGP1.jpg
as you can see it is 3 images on one big image. Each one of the images is for a different bit one for "portfolio" one for "about" etc.

Comment: Can you create a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I just want to ask you one question which isn't related to your issue. Why are you using CSS3 to do that simple task? I would definitely use simple jQuery animation which is also much wider supported

Comment: how would I use a jquery animation? can you link me to something for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use .Animate instead .css**
[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp)

```
 $("#content").animate({
    backgroundPositionX:"xpos", 
    backgroundPositionY:"ypos"
    },5000);
```

**tip:backgroundPositionX:"+=200px" set value to value=value+200 in px**

Comment: thankyou soo much :D One question: is there any way to make it less jumpy when it animates or is that just lag/connection?

Comment: $(selector).animate({params},speed,callback); change speed to lower value